# Doctrine ORM Bind Product to Multiple Entities

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have businesses, categories and products. Categories are assigned to businesses and products are assigned to categories and businesses.

Reason being, one product can be assigned to different categories in different businesses.

Business and Category entities are working fine, but I am not sure how to write a Product entity to achieve what I need...

**Business Entity:**

```
namespace Raiel\AFMage\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="businesses")
 */
class Business {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="businesses")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="business_categories",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="business_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * Default constructor, initializes collections
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**Category Entity:**

```
<?php

namespace Raiel\AFMage\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
 */
class Category {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Business", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    private $businesses;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreePath
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=3000, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(name="lvl", type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(name="lft", type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(name="rgt", type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\Column(name="root", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $children;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->children   = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->businesses = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Also, $business->addCategory works fine but $category->addBusiness doesn't save to DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product entity will probably look something like:

```
namespace Raiel\AFMage\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */
class Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="product_categories",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Business", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="product_businesses",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="business_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    private $businesses;
}
```

So more or less what you have for your Business entity but with the ManyToMany relation using a different join table.

And to make `$category->addBusiness()` work then you'll probably want to add a `cascade` option to category, thusly:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Business", mappedBy="categories", cascade="persist")
 */
private $businesses;
```

This informs Doctrine that anything new added to the `$businesses` array collection should be persisted, take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#synchronizing-bidirectional-collections) for details.

Comment: For example I want to know what products are in category x for business y

Comment: I figured out how to get products the way I need them, now only the part where it wouldn't do $category->addBusiness() left...